# Ubuntu 10.04 with ext4 gets repeated IO errors

Tags: raid, ubuntu-10.04, hard-drive, ext4

we installed a new DELL server with the (not supported) Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. We configured a hardware RAID (I think RAID 1) with the DELL tools before installing Ubuntu.

The server is not under load at all, a small Postgres Server and some Samba shares are active. Sometimes the harddisk seems to file and ubuntu mounts the filesystem as read-only.

Rebooting and running fsck helps for the moment, but the the problem occurs again and again..

Today I saw an error message at the time it happened (saving a large file to harddisk):

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Aborting journal on device dm-0-8
EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_start_sb: Detected a (...) journal
EXT4-fs (dm-0): Remounting filesystem read-only
EXT4-fs (dm-0): 
EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): in ext4_da_write_end: IO failure
This should not happen!! Data will be lost
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 1024 pages, in (...)1010855; err -30
```

It looks like an hardware error to me.
Do you think the RAID can be the cause? The FUSE filesystem installed (which is actually not used any more)? Could the problem be that Ubuntu is not supported on this DELL server, so could using Windows solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem.  Rebooting and fsck'ing will not cure the underlying problem, take the server offline to avoid data loss and run some checks.

Check the RAID hardware's boot utility, they sometimes have a check integrity option.  Be very careful as some low level integrity checks will destroy the data on the disks.  Check for any BIOS logs for warnings.

The problem could be a faulty disk in the array (without a fail over backup), check for a different coloured light on the server.

Depending on your disk controller you can also, in linux (ubuntu) use the GSmartControl to get the disks to report what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, the hardware RAID created a "Dell VIRTUAL DISK" which does not support SMART monitoring. So I guess I will check the Dell utilities..